# Connect to AWS account via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to login to AWS account via AWS CLI.

I imagine the first port of call with anything AWS CLI is to connect via the terminal.

How do I do this with AWS CLI

Comment: You can't *log in* to an AWS via the AWS CLI. You'd have to write your own custom tool, depending on the design, would use some sort of authentication and autorization and then open a browser to get to the console.

Comment: Found this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-quickstart.html

Comment: he's asking how to authenticate the was cli tool? that's all

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Was wondering why there wasn't any docs online for my ignorant assumption. Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
aws configure
```

it will ask for your `access key`, `secret key` & your default `region`.

[AWS CLI Quickstart - Configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html)